# Setting up Continuous Integration of Protractor using Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, protractor

I am writing automation test scripts using Protractor and now I need to set up the CI for this using Jenkins.

Tasks it needs to perform are:

1. Starting the selenium standalon server.
2. Starting the test using conf.js file.
3. Stopping the selenium standalone server.

Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 38):

I created a small **bash script** to do this.

```
# start selenium
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# wait until selenium is up
while ! curl http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status &>/dev/null; do :; done

# run the build
grunt cibuild --force

# stop selenium
curl -s -L http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This script is invoked from a *free-style project* in jenkins (`Build > Execute shell)`

[image]

Then the test result report is generated by reading the protractor test results. Hence, you have to produce junit reports from protractor, (look [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e7873093ada02ad6c9d6e190b7184775ab3686ce/docs/referenceConf.js#L200-L214)) :

```
onPrepare: function() {
  // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
  // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
  // this until inside the onPrepare function.
  require('jasmine-reporters');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true));
},
```

To make the report visible in jenkins i add a post build action in the job: `Publish JUnit test result report`:

[image]

Comment: I get a "undefined is not a function"  when trying to use the "jasmine" object to do the part " jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(...." any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have jasmine in your dependencies ?

Comment: fixed with var: jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');  ..................new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('protractor_output', true, true, 'testresults.e2e.')  

but now this generated a new issue :( 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730495/nodejs-protractor-jasmine-junitxmlreporter-runs-the-test-but-without-waiting

Comment: Make sure you're using jasmine-reporters v1.0.0, later versions aren't supported at the moment https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-produce-an-xml-report-of-my-test-results

Comment: Can you add a section to the answer that goes through the next step of making the reports visible in Jenkins?

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you could run this as a Grunt Task. First install grunt on Jenkins. Install the NPM packages for protractor_webdriver and protractor. Setup the configuration file to point the the node_module path and config file paths.

http://sideroad.secret.jp/articles/grunt-on-jenkins/

Then install protractor node modules. The Gruntfile would look similar to this. I created a test directory where the conf and spec files would be located.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    protractor_webdriver: {
        your_target: {
            options: {
                path: 'node_modules/protractor/bin/',
                command: 'webdriver-manager start'
            }
        }
    }, 
    protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: "node_modules/protractor/referenceConf.js", // Default config file
            keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
            noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
            args: {
            // Arguments passed to the command
            }
        },
        your_target: {
            options: {
                configFile: "test/conf.js", // Target-specific config file
                args: {} // Target-specific arguments
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('p:test', [
    'protractor_webdriver',
    'protractor'
]);  
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this works for a UNIX system, but it definitely doesn't work on Windows... Selenium works in the foreground, so the task never releases and hangs after 'Starting Selenium server'...

Answer (score 7):

The newest protractor allows you to run the selenium standalone server directly from the conf.js (or whatever protractor entry point you have).

comment out (or delete) the `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',` line, and replace it with `seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/latest.jar'`.

*`latest.jar` isn't installed by default, I created it as a symlink to the latest version installed via `npm install protractor --save`. This gives longer life to my `conf.js` files in the same directory.
Within the `./node_modules/protractor/selenium/` folder I ran `ln -s selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar latest.jar`*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gulp which is far simpler.

After [installing gulp in Jenkins System](http://omcfarlane.co.uk/install-gulp-js-windows/) , you may install the npm dependencies(npm install) & run gulp tasks directly as windows batch command in Jenkins as below:

[image]
 In the background to make selenium server up and running and providing various other parameters , you may use packages like 'gulp-angular-protractor' in the gulpfile.js as below:

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

 var gulp = require('gulp'),
 gulpProtractorAngular = require('gulp-angular-protractor'),
 gulpStart = gulp.Gulp.prototype.start,
 currentStartTaskName;

 gulp.Gulp.prototype.start = function (task) {
    currentStartTaskName = task;
    gulpStart.apply(this, arguments);
};
function executeWebTests(suiteName, appName) {
    return gulp.src([])
        .pipe(gulpProtractorAngular({
            'configFile': './conf.js',
            'debug': false,
            'autoStartStopServer': true,
            args: [
                '--suite', suiteName,
                '--capabilities.browserName', 'chrome',
                '--params.APPNAME', appName,
                '--params.SUITENAME', currentStartTaskName,
                '--capabilities.platformName', 'Windows'],
            keepAlive: false
        }))
        .on('error', function (e) {
            console.log('Ended with below ERROR::',e);
            process.exit(1);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Test complete');
            process.exit();
        });
}

gulp.task('RegressionSuiteTask', function () {
    executeWebTests('regressionTests,','Application_Name');
});
```

**conf.js**

```
 suites: {
          regressionTests: ['testCases/**/*.js']//will run all specs in subfolders 
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this already resolved and want to target for beginner to create Jenkins job and running test. I suggest to use selenium-server-standalone jar in configuration file and call configuration file from Jenkins.
**conf.js**

```
    ..  
    exports.config = {
        //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',  
        seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar',
    ....
    //html reporter logic
    .....
```

**Creating Jenkins Job**

- Install node js on Jenkins Server
- Install [Html Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) for end to end testing report
- Create Freestyle Project or whatever your needs
- Go to Build Section -> Add build step and choose Execute Windows
  batch command if Jenkins server in Windows otherwise choose Execute
  Shell for Linux

[image]

- Call conf.js (install packages and call your configuration file)

[image]

- For reporting Got to Post-Build Actions Section -> Add Publish Html
  Reports and call your report file (file assuming from root of your
  project)

[image]

However you can customize execution command using gulp or similar other packages. Thanks