# Nodejs Protractor + Jasmine + JUnitXmlReporter runs the test but without waiting for the browser

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor, jasmine-node

Im doing end to end testing of a Angular website using protractor, but wanted to export the results to a file that Jenkins can read (JUnitXmlReporter), so for this to work I need to do a "simple change" to my protractor config file on the "onPrepare":

```
exports.config = {
  // Do not start a Selenium Standalone sever - only run this using chrome.
  framework: 'jasmine',
  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  specs: [
    './test1.js',
    './test2.js'
  ], 
  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-node-reporter-fix');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
             new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('protractor_output', true, true, 'testresults.e2e.');
  }
};
```

but once I add this "onPrepare" code, **all the test run without waiting for the browser to render the html**. If I remove the "onPrepare" code, all the test will start working as expected, but no files generated for jenkins.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for the browser's promise.

```js
onPrepare: function() {
  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-node-reporter-fix');
  var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
  capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter(
        'protractor_output', true, true, 'testresults.e2e.');
  }
}
```

That said, if you are using Protractor, then you may need to call the `JUnitXmlReporter` off the `jasmine` object, not `jasmineReporters`.  I'm not using `node-jasmine` or `jasmine-node-reporter-fix`, so I can't speak to how the reporter gets exported, but on `"jasmine-reporters":"~1.0.0"` the reporter was still attached to the `jasmine` object.

https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters#protractor