# How do we stop webdriver-manager?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am using npm package webdriver-manager to start driver on machine.
It fails if the driver is already started.

Is there a way that I can stop and restart the webdriver? Or something like ignore if already started?

Comment: Can you please explain your question a little bit more? How do you want to restart webdriver? Is it manually or through the code?

Comment: Through node.js code

Comment: Webdriver-manager cannot be stopped. All hail webdriver-manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Protractor, you can add `seleniumServerJar` to your config file, and protractor will start/stop the selenium server for you.

```
exports.config = {
seleniumServerJar: "path/to/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar",
...
```

Comment: I was not successful by adding this command. I got following error.
C:\Users\xyx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:145:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:259:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)

Answer (score 3):

In bash you can close like this

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep webdriver | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338019/setting-up-continuous-integration-of-protractor-using-jenkins)

```
# stop selenium
curl -s -L http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-selenium-webdriver
thanks.