# Best way to kick off Protractor/Jasmine suites over night?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, automation, jasmine, protractor

Tools: Protractor 4.0.5, Jasmine 2.5.1, Windows 10

So currently I had tried to set up simple batch files that

1. Started selenium server
2. Launched a protractor config with a full test suite parameter
3. Launched a second protractor config with different full test suites on a different website
4. Killed the server

With those batch files I just set up a windows scheduled task to kick them off at specific times during the night. This sort of worked, but it only seemed to work while I was physically watching it happen and any time I left it over night it resulted with odd process codes such as (0x1) or (0x64) and no reports were ever generated for the tests as they should have been.

Is there a better/easier/more stable way of doing this? I know of Grunt and I know of Jenkins, so if those are your recommendations, would you be able to point me to solid resources that explain how to get it up and running using those tools? I am not familiar by any means with them.

Comment: Yes, use a proper CI system like Jenkins (or Concourse or Bamboo or ..., or perhaps something hosted like Travis or Circle or ...). Recommendations are off topic here, though.

Comment: any sources on getting up and running with Jenkins?  I've just installed it but haven't found too much on integrating it with protractor.

Comment: *"any sources"* is also a request for off-site resources, thus off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a robust CI eco-system built around Jenkins with couple of slaves hosted on good infrastructure

I saw a beautiful answer in this stackoverflow post - [Setting up Continuous Integration of Protractor using Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338019/setting-up-continuous-integration-of-protractor-using-jenkins)