# How to integrate maven with Protractor for CI/CD

Tags: maven, protractor

I am using Protractor for Automation. We are planning to move to CI/CD. Scripting is being done on .js files.However, we do not have Maven setup. Need help with Integrating Maven with Protractor, so that Jenkins can talk to Maven and trigger the build to run automation scripts.

Much appreciate your help !!
Thanks,
deepti.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is an unnecessary additional step in this context. You can directly trigger your Protractor tests from Jenkins either as a build-step or post build step. There are lot of great articles on the same

I quoted some below

[Setting up Continuous Integration of Protractor using Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338019/setting-up-continuous-integration-of-protractor-using-jenkins)

https://tobythetesterblog.wordpress.com/2014/10/26/getting-started-with-protractor-to-automate-e2e-tests-for-angularjs-apps/

UPDATE: Assuming that there is a common Problem statement across all CI/CD implementations. **Jenkins is setup on a remote Machine. My protractor setup is on a different machine setup exclusively for continuous testing**

Solution:

1. Configure your machine(which was exclusively setup for Protractor testing with all dependencies) as slave for your Jenkins.
   Refer [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)
2. Configure a job to be run only this new node. Refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/359793/tell-jenkins-to-run-a-specific-project-on-a-particular-slave-node)
3. Add a build step - Windows shell on the new Job to trigger Protractor tests.

`Protractor protractor.conf.js`

Comment: Thank you, Adithya !! As part of CI / CD, I am going to have the Protractor set up on my machine. However, I will need to run the scripts on a remote machine (having all the node modules installed) and send the results back to test management tool on my machine. Can you please help, how can Jenkins interact with my protractor scripts to trigger the scripts to run on a remote VDI.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Deeptig .. looks this is your first post :) .. I have udpated the answer