# How to run protractor JS script through jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, protractor

I have automated angular app using protractor and now I just want to kickoff the automation test though Jenkins. Could you please advise me the steps to do this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338019/setting-up-continuous-integration-of-protractor-using-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains the jenkins-protractor-headlesschrome setup:

https://gist.github.com/praphull27/6950d2a6c76a6e68acb7